# Using Thread with Plot is producing error messages

Tags: plotting, functions, warning-messages

I have this code:

```
phi[t_] := t_0 + c*Exp[-k*t];
k = 1.5; t_0 = 60;
Thread[
  Plot[Table[phi[t] /. c -> i, {i, -15, 15, 5}], {t, 0, 3}, 
    PlotRange -> {45, 75}]]
```

Which, as expected, produces the plot:

[image: Plot of Integral Curves]

However, mathematica is also spitting some weird error messages at me:

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in [image: Error Image] cannot be combined.

When I hover over the image in the error I get a list of a dozen other error messages:

> RGBColor called with 1 argument; 3 or 4 arguments expected.
>
> Coordinate Skeleton[77] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
>
> Coordinate Skeleton[77] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
>
> Coordinate Skeleton[77] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
>
> Coordinate Skeleton[52] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
>
> Coordinate Skeleton[77] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
>
> Coordinate Skeleton[77] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
>
> Coordinate Skeleton[77] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

I searched for the three different types of error messages given and none of the results I found seem to be relevant to my "problem" (If you can call it that: my graph looks fine, mathematica is just complaining for some weird reason).

Is this a bug, or is there something subtle that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Plot` has the native ability to "thread" the functions.

```
phi[t_] := t0 + c*Exp[-k*t];
{k, t0} = {1.5, 60};
Plot[Table[phi[t] /. c -> i, {i, -15, 15, 5}] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 3},  PlotRange -> {45, 75}]
```

[image]

Also note that `t_0` is not $t_0$ as in $\LaTeX$, because `t_` represents the `Blank[]` pattern associated with `t`.

And you can force the evaluation of the argument to `Plot` with `Evaluate` to make different colors.

Comment: Wow, I guess I should have read the documentation for `Plot` more closely. Thank you.

Comment: I actually have it as `Subscript[T, 0]` in my code, but it looks different on StackExchange and I don't know enough Latex to properly fix it.

Comment: I'd edit my answer to fix it, but that would take away the context of the comment in your answer

Comment: @Josie, except for formatting purposes, I would advice that you stay away from using subscripts.